# Overall Score Based on Top Three Score

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with this data

```
+------+-----+————-----+
|Props  |Score|Type     |
+------+-----+-------- +
|1.EY  |   30|Core
|2.FG  |   29|Core
|2.YUE |   29|Core
|3.VB. |   28|Elective
|4.RX. |   67|Elective                            
|5.XE. |   89|Elective                            
|6.TF. |   60|Elective                            
|7.HK  |   76|Elective             
|8.ER  |   58|Elective
```

I want to calculate the overall score by adding all Core scores plus any of the three best Elective scores. I cant seem to find my way around it.

Expected Results is 320: 3 Core Score + 3 best Elective 
i.e(30+29+29)+(89+76+67)

Comment: based on your sample update your question and add  your expected  result

Comment: Add your more requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNION ALL for the 2 cases of scores and then sum over the returned scores:

```
select sum(t.score) totalscore
from (
  select score from tablename
  where type = 'Core'
  union all
  select t.score from (
    select score from tablename
    where type = 'Elective'
    order by score desc
    limit 3
  ) t  
) t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gPTcByac1F5GqgLTDjGwGA/1).
Result:

```
| totalscore |
| ---------- |
| 320        |
```

Comment: How do  i add a group by if i want group the totalscore by students,  ie overal score for every student

Comment: You can't add a group by in this query because there is nothing to group by. This code sums scores under conditions.

Comment: Ok.  Please how can i sum them according to  students am kinda new to sql

Comment: Your current requirement, sample data and expected results do not involve any grouping, not even the word *student*. If you have a new requirement post a new question with all the relevant sample data, expected results and explain what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could rank the records by type within type partitions in an inner query and do a conditional sum in the outer query, like:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN type = 'Core' THEN score
        WHEN type = 'Elective' AND rn <= 3 THEN score
        ELSE 0
    END) res
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY score DESC) rn
    FROM mytable t
) x
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle with your sample data](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mE4fJLds1FbKuWpkMV7ukw/1)**:

```
| res |
| --- |
| 320 |
```